# Unable to use a set variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hi
I have this code in my batch file

```
set destpath = "C:\"

copy help.txt %destpath%

pause
```

But I see that the command that gets executed while running the batch file is

```
copy help.txt
```

The batch file is not recognizing the 'destpath' variable at all. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no space before the equal sign. 
Try

```
set destpath=c:\
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

don't use spaces: `set destpath="C:\"`